# Javascript plugin pattern: extendable or closures?

Tags: javascript

Note: I'm not sure if this belongs here or on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), but I was kinda afraid that they'd move it to StackOverflow anyway because of the JavaScript.

I'm figuring out what pattern to use for a plugin I'm writing. When I'm looking at other plugins, the top one is fairly popular (I use Underscore.js's `_.extend` method for this example). What I don't like about it, is that I need to use `this` everywhere which I think might hurt minification and makes my code harder to read. On the other hand, it's really easy to extend.

```
var App = function(options) {
    this.initialize(options);
};

_.extend(App.prototype, {
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.options = options || {};
        this.doStuff();
    },
    doStuff: function() {
        if (this.options.talk) {
            return "Doing stuff.";
        }               
    }
});

var myApp = new App();
myApp.hasOptions = function() { return !!this.options; }; // will return false
```

The alternative is using closures. The big benefit is that code is easy to read, and none of it is exposed (the methods are more or less private). The problem with this though is that it's not extendable.

```
var App = function(options) {
    options = options || {};

    function initialize() {
        doStuff();
    };

    function doStuff() {
        if (options.talk) {
            return "Doing stuff.";
        }
    };

    initialize();
};

var myApp = new App();
myApp.hasOptions = function() { return !!options; }; // will throw a ReferenceError
```

I don't think my plugin needs extendability; it's a text in/html out plugin. And I could add support for a couple of event callbacks to help other developers tie it in with their apps.

Am I overlooking something? Should I go for the extendable code anyway, will I get into trouble using closures?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann thanks, why don't you change your comment into an answer?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "plugin"? Where should it be plugged in? How should it be used?

Comment: @Bergi it would be used in a web based content management system to help write more readable texts. The minimum implementation would be something like stating `var betterText = new BetterText({...});` where the options hash contain a couple of HTML element selectors (textarea for input, div for output) and perhaps optional markdown support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of private is really a language thing, and I wouldn't let it dictate your design.

This could get minified to `a = this; a.foo();`

Fighting over bytes that gzip really well isn't worthwhile. Most of the overhead is in establishing a TCP connection; an extra packet isn't so noticeable. Closures also have a lot of overhead to them, and you end up with different objects representing identical functions. This isn't a problem if you're creating one instance, but it can start to add up.